Reducing product of powers of logarithm
I am trying to show that

$$(\log(a))^n (\log(b))^m = P(\log(a^ib^j)), \quad i,j \in \{-1,0,1\}$$

where $P$ is a polynomial and $n \ge m \ge 1$ are natural numbers. Using Binomial identities for the cases $(n,m) \in \{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$, I was able to obtain $$ \log(a)\log(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ (\log(ab))^2-(\log(a))^2-(\log(b))^2 \right] \\ 
\left(\log\left(a\right)\right)^{2}\log\left(b\right) = \frac{1}{6}\left((\log\left(ab\right))^{3}-(\log\left(ab^{-1}\right))^{3}-2(\log\left(b\right))^{3}\right)\\
\left(\log\left(a\right)\right)^{2}\left(\log\left(b\right)\right)^{2}= \frac{1}{12}\left(\log\left(ab\right)^{4}+\log\left(ab^{-1}\right)^{4}-2\log\left(a\right)^{4}-2\log\left(b\right)^{4}\right)
$$
Is this true for larger values of $n$ and $m$ ? For $n=3,m=1$, I am stuck at $$\log\left(a\right)^{3}\log\left(b\right) = \frac{1}{8}\left(\log\left(ab\right)^{4}-\log\left(ab^{-1}\right)^{4}-8\log\left(a\right)\log\left(b\right)^{3}\right).$$
I am not sure how to get rid of the third term on the right side. For which $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is the given statement true?
Edit : $P$ can be written as $$P = \sum_{k=1}^{M} \sum_{i,j \in \{-1,0,1 \}}a_{i,j,k} (\log(a^ib^j))^k.$$
Addendum: A great idea by @Jair to simplify notation is to substitute $x=\log{a}$ and $y=\log{b}$. Then the above three equations can be written as $$ xy = \frac{1}{2}\big( (x+y)^2-x^2-y^2\big) \\ x^2y = \frac{1}{6}\left((x+y)^3-(x-y)^3-2y^3 \right) \\ 
x^2y^2 = \frac{1}{12}\left( (x+y)^4+(x-y)^4-2x^4-2y^4\right)$$
and $P =  \sum_{k=1}^{M} \sum_{i,j \in \{-1,0,1 \}}a_{i,j,k} (ix+jy)^k$. The problem can be rephased as: Does their exist $M \in \mathbb{N}$  such that for $n \ge m \ge 1$,

$$ x^n y^m = \sum_{k=1}^{M} \sum_{i,j \in \{-1,0,1 \}}a_{i,j,k} (ix+jy)^k$$


I don't understand. Say if $a=2,b=2$, then $$\log(a)\log(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \log(ab)^2-\log(a)^2-\log(b)^2 \right]$$ is false. RHS is always returning $0$.

The square is on the entire log, $(\log(ab))^2$, so the RHS is $(\log(2))^2$ @Gwen

Now it's alright.

If I understand you correctly, this really doesn't need to be a question about logarithms. You can set $x = \log a,$ $y = \log b$ and then $\log (a^i b^j) = ix + jy$ and so you are looking for $x^n y^m$ as a polynomial in the variables $(ix + jy)$.

Why can't you just take $(\log a)^n (\log b)^m = P(\log(a^1b^0), \log(a^0b^1))$ where $P(x,y) = x^n y^m$? That is a polynomial.

@JairTaylor $P$ is a polynomial of one variable,but I see what you mean. I will edit the problem.

@JairTaylor yes, now that I look at it, you are absolutely correct. Does this make the problem easier ?

I understand now what you mean, after the edit. I don't know if the formulation without logs makes it easier, but it at least puts it in the more standard language of polynomial identities, which are well studied.

For up to $x^2y^2$ we have, as you have found,
\begin{equation} x^1 y^1 = -\frac{1}{4}(x - y)^{2} + \frac{1}{4}(x + y)^{2} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x^2 y^1 = -\frac{1}{6}(x - y)^{3} + \frac{1}{6}(x + y)^{3} + -\frac{1}{3}y^{3} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x^2 y^2 = \frac{1}{12}(x - y)^{4} + \frac{1}{12}(x + y)^{4} + -\frac{1}{6}x^{4} + -\frac{1}{6}y^{4} \end{equation}
but I haven't been able to find identities for larger degree.

yeah @JairTaylor I am stuck at this point as well

In polynomial terms, we need to (dis)prove that for each $n,m$ there are $A(x),\dots,D(x)$ such that
$$
x^n y^m = A(x-y)+B(x+y)+C(x)+D(y).
$$
Note that only $a_{k},\dots,d_{k}$ for $k=n+m$ actually contribute to terms $x^i y^j$ such that $i+j=k$. At the same time, if we consider the expansion of the corresponding expression
$$
a(x-y)^k + b(x+y)^k  + cx^k + dy^k,
$$
we'll notice that terms of $a(x-y)^k$ and $b(x+y)^k$ cancel each other out only when $|a|=|b|$, after which the number of terms becomes either $\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac{k+1}{2}\rceil$, depending on whether the signs of $a$ and $b$ match. After that, we have the following options with regard to $cx^k + dy^k$:

If $k$ is even and $\lceil\frac{k+1}{2} \rceil$ terms remained, we may cancel $2$ more for the total of $\frac{k}{2}-1$.
If $k$ is odd, we may cancel one more term for the total of $\frac{k-1}{2}$.

As you see, starting with $k=5$, the minimum number of terms is at least $2$, so it is not possible to represent $x^n y^m$ in the desired form when $n+m \geq 5$.
